# Ag-grid last release 23.1.0 getPopupPosition() in cell editor not working

Tags: ag-grid, angular9

in my typeahead component cell editor, the cellEditor display under the editable cell, and I want to display it over the cell; I used the getPopupPosition function, but it is not working in ag-grid cell editor last release.(So I need to fix it like the first Picture).Thanks.

[when I click the cell in first row the editor open over the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9hhp.png)

[when I click the cell in first row the editor open under the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTpnQ.png)

Comment: Even I'm having similar issue. Just posting some screen shot won't help. Can you share some code or at least a stack blitz to debug the issue?

Comment: Thanks to reply, ag-grid will fix it in the next release. https://www.ag-grid.com/ag-grid-pipeline/ the issue code AG-4200

Comment: Thanks for the reply!!

Comment: The issue has been resolved by ag-grid in version 23.1.1. Please update your version and this issue will be resolved.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know !!